# CMD - Format environment variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For example if `%USERNAME% = foo.bar`, I would like to change it to be `FooBar` - removing the dot and camel casing.

So far I've only attempted to remove the "dot",

```
@echo off
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set new=!%USERNAME%:.=!
echo %new%
```

but this returns `.=`. I'm not very good with Windows batch scripting (obviously) so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

SET "name=foo.bar"

ECHO was:%name%
SET "name=.%name%"
FOR %%L IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO SET "name=!name:.%%L=.%%L!"
SET "name=%name:.=%"

ECHO now:%name%

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: @MattWilliamson: the var:string1=string2 mechanism is case-insensitive for string1 and the replacement is exactly what is specified in string2. The rest is the magic of delayedexpansion.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
set new=%USERNAME:.=%
echo %new%
```

Comment: one `%` too much (probably a typo?)

Comment: Yes, sorry and Thanks

Comment: Thank you, sachadee. This fixed the issue of removing the dot.